# HI, question related to list of values in data model. I'm facing error issue while executing query

Tags: oracle, cloud, erp, fusion

In oracle fusion i tried to create  list of values in data model, for that list of values i write a query to display the required info when i selected a p_suppliers, it shows error like this
***Error***
(**Parameter name: psuppliersitecode oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1**
)

***Query:***

```
SELECT VENDOR_SITE_CODE 
FROM POZ_SUPPLIER_SITES_V 
where VENDOR_ID IN( 
    SELECT VENDOR_ID 
    FROM POZ_SUPPLIERS_V 
    WHERE VENDOR_NAME=NVL(:P_SUPPLIER,VENDOR_NAME)
)
```

solution for that problem

Comment: I don't see how the message relates to the error. Are you sure that's the code that's causing it? Maybe showing how you're calling it would help.

Comment: Yes, it is the code that i am facing the problem